# What does #(loc.InstallAcceptCheckbox) etc. refer to in WiX burn themes?

Tags: wix

In the default Wix Theme I see

`<Page Name="Install">
        <Text Name="InstallVersion" X="11" Y="-41" Width="210" Height="17" FontId="3" DisablePrefix="yes" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.InstallVersion)</Text>
        <Checkbox Name="EulaAcceptCheckbox" X="-11" Y="-41" Width="260" Height="17" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.InstallAcceptCheckbox)</Checkbox>
        <Button Name="OptionsButton" X="-171" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.InstallOptionsButton)</Button>
        <Button Name="InstallButton" X="-91" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.InstallInstallButton)</Button>
        <Button Name="WelcomeCancelButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.InstallCloseButton)</Button>
    </Page>`

What does the #(loc.name) stuff refer to? I'm assuming it's a variable, but where are they set?

I have my own TextBox on the Options page which I default to a particular value, but whenever you go back to the page, any previously entered value will revert to the default.

I'm assuming this wouldn't happen if the TextBox value was that of a variable - whatever the user entered would be stored in the variable, and they'd see that value if they exited the Options page and returned to it.

I could then initialise this variable to the value I wanted.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The #(loc.variable) stuff is to do with localisation. You can find the defaults in your WiX Toolset SDK/themes folder under HyperlinkTheme.xml.

In regards to having the entered value save between page changes, putting a variable under you  works, as long as its name is the same as your WiX Theme UI element:

```
<Variable Name="TestVariable" Type="numeric" Value="8443" />
```